# Swift-based iOS App Extension using NSExtension

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am experimenting with daemon processes on iOS using the NSExtension private API.

I have been following Ian McDowell's article [Multi-Process iOS App Using NSExtension](https://ianmcdowell.net/blog/nsextension/). A sample project is available for download at the end of the article.

My goal is to port this sample project from Objective-C to Swift. It has been simple enough porting the AppDelegate and ViewController to swift for the host application. XCode 9.2 seems to map the NSExtension method declarations in PrivateHeaders.h to Swift for use.

**PrivateHeaders.h**

```
@interface NSExtension : NSObject

+ (instancetype)extensionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier error:(NSError **)error;
- (void)beginExtensionRequestWithInputItems:(NSArray *)inputItems completion:(void (^)(NSUUID *requestIdentifier))completion;
- (int)pidForRequestIdentifier:(NSUUID *)requestIdentifier;
- (void)cancelExtensionRequestWithIdentifier:(NSUUID *)requestIdentifier;
- (void)setRequestCancellationBlock:(void (^)(NSUUID *uuid, NSError *error))cancellationBlock;
- (void)setRequestCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSUUID *uuid, NSArray *extensionItems))completionBlock;
- (void)setRequestInterruptionBlock:(void (^)(NSUUID *uuid))interruptionBlock;

@end
```

I run into trouble when trying to port the application extension class from Objective-C to Swift. Below is a simplification of the original class and my port:

**Extension.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Extension : NSObject <NSExtensionRequestHandling>

@end
```

**Extension.m**

```
#import "Extension.h"

@implementation Extension

- (void)beginRequestWithExtensionContext:(NSExtensionContext *)context {
    NSLog(@"Beginning request with context: %@", [context description]);
}

@end
```

**Extension.swift**

```
import Foundation

class Extension: NSObject, NSExtensionRequestHandling {
    func beginRequest(with context: NSExtensionContext) {
        print("Beginning request with context: \(context.description)")
    }
}
```

Attempting to launch the Swift `Extension` process result in the following error in XCode:

> Unable to setup extension context - error: Couldn't communicate with a helper application.

Inspecting the iPhone log via Apple Configurator 2 reveals the following error:

> iPhone Extension(CoreFoundation)[366] : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** - [__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil

Is anyone able to provide any additional insight into what might be going wrong here? The swap from Objective-C to Swift seems to be straightforward. I cannot even hit a breakpoint on the Extension application before it seems to crash.

Note: I understand that this likely wouldn't make it past app store review. It will never be going near the app store.

Comment: Update for anyone playing along at home. I didn't solve this, but keeping 'Extension' class as Objective-C running Swift code from there works okay.

Comment: Hi Jordan! Could you please share sample project as original link in McDowell's article is expired?